# String that is a number broken into in array

Tags: java

I am trying to split a string thats a big number like `123456789` into an int array like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` but having some trouble. should be simple enough but my output is funky. here is what I have so far:

```
public static boolean swap(String cc){
    boolean isvalid = false;
    int [] num = new int[cc.length()];
    for(int i = 1; i < cc.length(); i++){
        num [i] = Integer.parseInt(cc.substring(0, 1));
    }


    for(int x=0;x<num.length;x++){
        System.out.println(num[x]);
    }
    return isvalid;
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to do it..? I am having trouble because my method does not work.

Comment: How about String.toCharArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the following line:

```
num [i] = Integer.parseInt(cc.substring(0, 1));
```

with:

```
num [i] = Integer.parseInt(cc.substring(i, i+1));
```

if you want to iterate the characters. Otherwise you'll keep choosing the same character over and over again.

Comment: @chilliq nope. `charAt()` returns a `char` not a `String` (and `parseInt` takes a string as an argument)

Answer (score 2):

There are more cleaner approaches to doing this, but if you are dead set on using your method, there are a couple of errors that you need to fix for this to work:

- Your `for` loop index is starting at 1 when it should start at 0.
- In your loop, you are repeatedly just parsing the first character of the string.  As such, you should probably do this:

---

```
 for(int i = 0; i < cc.length(); i++){
     num [i] = Integer.parseInt(cc.substring(i, i+1));
 }
```

This way, you are accessing successive characters in your string.

---

As a minor sidenote, I don't get what the point of this function is.  All you're doing is splitting up the numbers in the string into separate elements in an array, but you don't seem to be doing anything else with this output.

Comment: out of curiosity, why use `.split("")` rather than `.toCharArray()`? the latter seems more intuitive and readable to me.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow - You're definitely right.  I just removed that nonsense because I was referring to the comments left by others, but they seem to have been removed.  As such, I just got rid of that statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many solutions. Here is a different approach that you can consider:

```
for (int c : cc) {
    num[i] = (c - 48)
}
```

It works because we can loop through the String as char. And char can be converted to int easily. 
In the 16-bit Unicode table, 0-9 are from 48-57 - which means if your char is in that range, you can just minus 48 to get the number.

Comment: `char` is a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit. So, use a Unicode table instead of an ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your first loop with following code

```
for(int i = 0; i < cc.length(); i++){
 num [i] = Integer.parseInt(cc.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

> Note: i should start from  **0**   ----- array